# Applying heat to a transistor

Tags: transistors, heat, thermistor

I witnessed an experiment in which a transistor was connected to an led and a power supply.

A lighter was used to heat up the transistor and this reduced the resistance of the circuit and made the led light up brightly.

Why does heating the transistor do this ?

And if this works with a transistor then why is  a thermistor needed ?

Comment: Heat agitates the silicon which releases more charges into the conduction band, reducing resistance. Part of the reason a thermistor is used is they have managed behaviors, though they usually also aren't used in conjunction with a lighter and an LED.

Comment: Thank you I understand now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transistor essentially lets through as much current (that's charge per time) as it has charge carriers available in a specially crafted thin zone.

The number of these carriers can, depending on the type of transistor, be changed by running a current through the base of the transistor, or by applying a potential between the gate and one of its other terminals.

But: Charge carriers also form spontaneously in semiconductors when the temperature is above absolute zero, and the speed at which that happens increases very much with the temperature. Thus, you can make a transistor act very well as a temperature sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance of a turned on transistor (in a switch configuration) is dependent on the free charges in it. The available free charges increase with the temperature. (More charge carrier will have the energy through the heat to jump out the atoms into a conductive energy band.)

In the equation for an MOS series series resistance the mobility and the gate-source overdrive voltage ([image: VGS-VTH]) is present in the denominator, both of which terms are increasing with the temperature. The process is similar on the bipolar transistor, where both the amount of free charges increases and the threshold voltage needed to turn it on as a switch reduces.

By definition a thermistor is a resistor which changes is resistance with temperature, but it is not the only way to measure temperature. You can use a transistor (both bipolar and field effect ones) to measure the temperature or the change of temperature. Search for PTAT and CTAT circuits if you are interested in the topic.